# WinJS Sample working with MS ASP.NET SignalR?

Tags: windows-8, winjs, signalr.client

I created the [SignalR QuickStart](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs) in VS2012. It is working fine on localhost:xxxx.
I added a Winforms project as SignalR client without problem.

Then, I added a Win8 WinJS application, but couldn't receive messages via SignalR.
Basically I get undefind on line

```
var chat = $.connection("http://localhost:39414/").chatHub;
```

Can anyone send a successful sample solution?

Answer (score 0):

There may be more to it, but for a start, Windows Store applications can't use a loopback connection.  [You can set it up as follows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh780593.aspx); however, this is for testing only, as an application with such a set up would not pass certification.